# c++ errors less verbose

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

We all love C++ producing verbose errors spanning two shell screens. Especially after you forget single ampersand in template function definition. And what you need is only first, and maybe last, line of the error message.

How to make C++ template errors less verbose?

Comment: Don't use gcc use vs instead :D.

Comment: ¤ See the FAQ item ["How can any human hope to understand these overly verbose template-based error messages?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.17). In short, the frequently given answer to that question, in the days of Usenet, was to use StlFilt (linked to in the FAQ). Note: the link given here is only to the main FAQ site at the moment. The FAQs item URL's change, and the FAQ is mirrored at umpteen sites. It's not really meant to be linked to directly. Anyway, it's often a Good Idea to read the FAQ before asking. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 3):

If you are using gcc (or g++) you could use the following options:

```
-Wfatal-errors -w
```

The `-Wfatal-errors` will make compilation stop on the first error, and `-w` will eliminate the warnings.

Not really something I'd suggest doing in most instances, but perhaps helpful in your case right now.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that GCC outputs notes like overload resolution candidates just as if they were errors. Turning `-Wfatal-errors` on you will get "ambiguous call", and be left wondering which are the ambiguous overloads, because each listing of an overload is "another error" for GCC. So, instead of twenty errors, sometimes you get half of an error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do that easily. What is possible, on the other hand, is to use colored output.

On Debian (and related), you can easily install colorgcc package, which does exactly that.

It helps a lot. It's not the same, but it really helps

Answer (score 1):

A better front-end like [LLVM clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) is probably the only option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [STLFilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html) to shorten the template error messages, it helps a lot!

An example of the filtering it does can be found at [Dr. Dobbs.](http://drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=184401416&siteSectionName=)